# Issue deleting from a sql database using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, sql, json, flask

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    username = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    sex = db.Column(db.String(20))
    birthdate = db.Column(db.String(50))
    joined = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    message = db.relationship('Message')



class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sender = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.username'))
    receiver = db.Column(db.String(100))
    message = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    time_sent = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())



@views.route('/delete_message', methods=['POST'])
def delete_message():
    message = json.loads(request.message)
    message_id = message['id']
    message = Message.query.get(message_id)
    if message:
        if message.sender == current_user.username:
            db.session.delete(message)
            db.session.commit()

    return jsonify({})


function delete_message(message_id) {
  fetch("/delete_message", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ message_id: message_id }),
  }).then((_res) => {
    window.location.href = "/";
  });
}



        <button type="button" class="close" onClick="delete_message({{ message.id }})">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
```

The first two classes are part of the python file to set up the database. The decorated function is part of the views python file. The next function is part of the javascript file. And the bottom section is part of the html file.

I am creating a message system, and I am having trouble deleting a message from an sql database using javascript and Flask. Pycharm says that "message" is an unresolved attribute reference to the class "request". Can anyone help me understand why the message will not delete form the database.db file.

Answer (score 0):

Use request.json() mehtod to get your json data

```
@views.route('/delete_message', methods=['POST'])
def delete_message():
    message = request.json()
    message_id = message['id']
    message = Message.query.get(
```

Br